# Resize image view to fit image, not other way around

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I'm using XCode 6 to develop an application for OSX using Swift. In my window I have an image view which displays different images depending on which entry is selected in a table just above it. All of the images that can be displayed are the same width, but different height.

What I would like is for the image view (and the window!) to resize depending on which image is selected. I have no idea of how to do this in the Interface Builder (which is what I have used (bindings etc.) for most of my app), and can't find any tutorials/questions about it, since searching always gives results for how to resize images to fit an image view, not the other way around!

If you need any more specific information about my app, please just let me know what you need.

**Edit:**
There are currently no constraints at all on anything in my window, but the only way I can see to edit the content hugging and compression resistance priorities is to have at least one constraint on the image view. Hence the top space constraint to the search bar above.

[image]

Comment: `imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,imageView.frame.origin.y,image.width,image.height)` should do the trick

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @KenThomases yes I am

Comment: @codingVoldemort would that change the size each time a new image is displayed?

Comment: If you are using auto layout, you would have to change the constraints programmatically too.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing this? Or is there some kind of demo project that I could download and look at to see?

Comment: You don't have to change the constraints. You can just set positional constraints (I.e. Centre) and the image view will size to fit automatically with auto layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using auto layout, you should make sure that the image view's Compression Resistance and Content Hugging priorities are both greater than 500 (which is `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut`). That way, changes to the image view's intrinsic content size will override the system's tendency to keep the window the same size.

It would probably be good to set the image view to do no scaling, too, but I'm not sure it's necessary.

Also, you need to make sure that your other constraints don't have the effect of fixing the size of the image view. Obviously, you should not have width or height constraints on the image view itself, but you also need everything else to be flexible enough to allow the image view to be any size. If you need help with that, you're going to have to show us the constraints within the window.

Comment: I've edited my question to include a screenshot of my current constraints (none). Just changing those values didn't seem to help...

Comment: If you're using auto layout, you need to set up constraints for your views. If you don't, then Xcode will install some constraints, but they're unlikely to do what you want. Also, you specifically want there to be a relationship between the size of the image view and the size of the window. You need to establish that relationship using constraints. For example, set Top, Bottom, Leading, and Trailing space constraints between the image view and its container view. (Or a chain of constraints like image view bottom to button top, button bottom to container bottom.)

Comment: I made a chain of constraints, and my image view now resizes. Thank you very much!